# Issue in generating token from ms-adal-angular6 package to authenticate powerbi report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, microsoft-adal-angular6

I am using **Angular 8**, **microsoft-adal-angular6** package for Login and **ngx-powerbi** package to embed Powerbi report

I have created Azure App Registration and given the Powerbi API permissions

[image]

I am using the below configurations for Azure AD login

```
{
    tenant: 'my tenant id',
    clientId: 'my client id',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
    tokenUrl: 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
    resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
    expireOffsetSeconds: 15 * 60
}
```

And I try to embed the powerbi report using the below code

```
<ngx-powerbi-component
    type="report"
    id="my-report-id"
    embedUrl="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=my-report-id&groupId=my-group-id"
    tokenType="Aad"
    [accessToken]="token from ADAL"
  ></ngx-powerbi-component>
```

I have enabled service principal access in powerbi side

But still I am getting [image]

If I generate AD token from Postman with

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/vca.com/oauth2/token
grant_type=password&client_id=[my_client_id]&client_secret=[my_client_secret]&resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api&username=[username]&password=[password]
```

and use the response token in the ngx-powerbi-component, I am able to view the report.

I am not able to figure out how to generate correct AD token from MS ADAL.

Comment: this has been a challenge for sure, did you end up having any luck figuring it out?